# Does heat affect spathiphyllum blossoming?

Tags: houseplants

I have two Spathiphyllums I keep in my flat, more or less similar (about the same age, pot size is similar, general plant size also similar), except for the conditions I keep them: one is in my bedroom, next to a north-facing window that never receives direct sunlight, **resting directly on top of an active radiator**. The other is in my living room, next to a south-facing very big window: plenty of light, although actual direct sunlight is limited, far from radiators and in a generally good-tempered environment.

The second plant grows fantastically, but didn't produce any flowers yet. The first plant has a slower growth (due to the low light condition, I guess), but ever since I put it on top of the radiator it's blossoming like I've never see before (see pic below). The "ever since I put it there" is kind of key too: the plant used to be next to the window, but not *on* the radiator, and it never bloomed before.

I've read nurseries use a special hormone to stimulate spath blossoming, but does temperature also play a part? I read spathiphyllum blooms mostly in spring, but the blooming of the one in my room started in December, with very low daylight, could it be I "tricked" the plant into thinking it's spring by the warmth alone?

[image: Spathiphyllum growing on radiator]

Comment: A "good tempered" environment for you might be a bit colder than ideal for the plants. The ideal temperature range for commercial production is quoted as 65 to 90 F (18 to 32 C) which may explain why one of your plants likes sitting on top of your radiator. They don't need bright light. Also, being a tropical rainforest plant where the environment is pretty constant all year round, they don't have a strong annual rhythm for flowering.

Comment: By good tempered I mean 20+ pretty much always (I never measured the trend, but at least for day temperature it's definitely t-shirt-ok year round, which I'd put at 20/22+)

Comment: One way to find out might be to take your other plant and place it next to this one on the radiator.

Comment: Yeah, although I don't have enough space for both there, I'd have to swap their positions. Since they both are quite acclimated to their locations, though, I don't think I will

Comment: (Moreover, radiators won't be on for much longer here, since spring is coming. To make a proper test I'd need to swap them next December and see what happens)

Comment: On the radiator it will be getting "bottom heat" into the soil, and also evaporating more water from the soil to increase the humidity around the plant. 20/22 is near the bottom of the 18-32 range. A few degrees might make all the difference.